# how to sort a triple in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I want to know how to sort the triple below based on the first column using C++?
Can I use std::map?

```
0 0 1
1 2 0
2 0 3
0 1 4
```

the wanted result is

```
0 0 1
0 1 4
1 2 0
2 0 3
```

Comment: How is stored the data originally ?

Comment: What happens if instead of having 203 you have 112, for example? Is it important the order of the rest of the columns or it's fine to have 001, 014, 120, 112 ?

Comment: @xunzhang do you need help for loading the file or only for "how to sort"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just use std::sort on, for example, a vector of std::tuple - the default comparison is lexicographic, so first column counts most.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are sorting a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

C++11:

```
std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec), [](const std::vector<int>& a,
                                   const std::vector<int>& b){
  return a[0] < b[0]; // sorting on the first column only
});
```

Assuming you want lexical order:

```
std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec));
```

Comment: And if `a[0]` and `b[0]` are the same?

Comment: @Zeda He did not they he was using `tuple` neither that he wanted to sort  on the second field as well

Comment: OK, agreed, OP only asks for sorting by the first column. My bad.

Comment: @KonradRudolph from the OP's question, it is not clear if they want lexicographical ordering, or whether preserving the relative ordering is good enough.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Nothing suggests the OP wants lexicographical order: he said "sort the triple below based on the first column".

Comment: The standard library already defines `std::vector::operator<` to do a lexicographical compare so your second example doesn't need the lambda function.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks I was not sure. Fixing

Comment: You still don't need the lambda, `std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec));` is sufficient and will do the correct thing.